# Парсинг вложенного JSON массива swift

Tags: json, swift, парсер

Мне необходимо распарсить json, который содержит массив с объектами. Видел много статей и ответов на эту тему, но найти ошибку в своём коде никак не могу. Надеюсь, что вы помежете

Сам json

```
[
    {
        "id": 707860,
        "name": "Hurzuf",
        "country": "UA",
        "coord": {
        "lon": 34.283333,
        "lat": 44.549999
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 519188,
        "name": "Novinki",
        "country": "RU",
        "coord": {
        "lon": 37.666668,
        "lat": 55.683334
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1283378,
        "name": "Gorkhā",
        "country": "NP",
        "coord": {
        "lon": 84.633331,
        "lat": 28
        }
    }
]
```

Как пытаюсь распарсить:

```
enum CityJsonRootKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, name, country, coord
}

enum CoordCityJsonKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case lon, lat
}

struct CityList: Decodable {
    var cities: [CityInfo]?
}

struct CityInfo: Decodable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var country: String?
    var lon: Float?
    var lat: Float?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        print("Into init")
        var unkeyedRootContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        while (!unkeyedRootContainer.isAtEnd) {

            let rootContainer = try unkeyedRootContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CityJsonRootKeys.self)

            self.id = try rootContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
            self.name = try rootContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
            self.country = try rootContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .country)

            let coordContainer = try rootContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CoordCityJsonKeys.self, forKey: .coord)
            self.lon = try coordContainer.decode(Float.self, forKey: .lon)
            self.lat = try coordContainer.decode(Float.self, forKey: .lat)
        }

    }
}

let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(CityList.self, from: jsonData)
print(results)
```

На экран ничего не выводится. Переменная `jsonData` содержит в себе json, что расписан выше, т.е. `let jsonData = """ [ { бла-бла } ]""".data(using: .utf8)!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ряд ошибок:

1. Неправильный тип "корня": `CityList` был бы, если JSON был `{"cities": […]}`, а он `[…]`, т.е. надо парсить массив, судя по всему `CityInfo`:

   ```
   let results = try JSONDecoder().decode([CityInfo].self, from: jsonData)
   print(results)
   ```
2. Ручной парсинг `CityInfo` неверен, там нет `unkeyedRootContainer`, если убрать то выходит такое:

   ```
   struct CityInfo: Decodable {
       var id: Int?
       var name: String?
       var country: String?
       var lon: Float?
       var lat: Float?

       init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
           print("Into init")

           let rootContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CityJsonRootKeys.self)

           self.id = try rootContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
           self.name = try rootContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
           self.country = try rootContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .country)

           let coordContainer = try rootContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CoordCityJsonKeys.self, forKey: .coord)
           self.lon = try coordContainer.decode(Float.self, forKey: .lon)
           self.lat = try coordContainer.decode(Float.self, forKey: .lat)
       }
   }
   ```

---

Код в целом:

```
let jsonData = """
[
  {
    "id": 707860,
    "name": "Hurzuf",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
       "lon": 34.283333,
       "lat": 44.549999
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 519188,
    "name": "Novinki",
    "country": "RU",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 37.666668,
      "lat": 55.683334
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1283378,
    "name": "Gorkhā",
    "country": "NP",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 84.633331,
      "lat": 28
    }
  }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

enum CityJsonRootKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, name, country, coord
}

enum CoordCityJsonKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case lon, lat
}

struct CityInfo: Decodable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var country: String?
    var lon: Float?
    var lat: Float?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        print("Into init")

        let rootContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CityJsonRootKeys.self)

        self.id = try rootContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try rootContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.country = try rootContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .country)

        let coordContainer = try rootContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CoordCityJsonKeys.self, forKey: .coord)
        self.lon = try coordContainer.decode(Float.self, forKey: .lon)
        self.lat = try coordContainer.decode(Float.self, forKey: .lat)
    }
}

let results = try JSONDecoder().decode([CityInfo].self, from: jsonData)
print(results)
```

Comment: Благодарю, всё работает, всё объяснили